# How to add a third party library when using angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I wanted to try out creating an Angular 2 app with angular-cli (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) and then use ng2-material (https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material) for UI components. But I just don't understand how / where I have to include the ng2-material library in order to use it.

I created a project with `ng new myproject` then I started the server with `ng serve` and opened the webpage which just worked out fine. Next step, I installed ng2-material with `npm install ng2-material --save`. Then I added `MATERIAL_PROVIDERS` to angular's bootstrap as is shown here https://github.com/AngularShowcase/angular2-seed-ng2-material/blob/master/app/bootstrap.ts.

This results in an error message `GET http://localhost:4200/ng2-material/all 404 (Not Found)` in the web browser, and I just can't figure out how to get rid of it.

angular-cli seems to be doing something to create a `dist`-folder where some of the node modules that are used in the index.html end up in, but I don't see where or how that's configured.

Comment: Go to `your_project/src/index.html`, there you have SystemJS config.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[EDIT 29/09/2016]** Now that angular-cli is using webpack iso system.js, this answer doesn't make a lot of sense anymore. Check the pages '[3d party lib installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib)' and '[global lib installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)' on the angular-cli wiki.

**[EDIT 10/05/2016]** This is now described in full detail on the [angular cli wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs).

This worked for me:

In the **ember-cli-build.js**, you add the dependency to the *vendorNpmFiles*, e.g.

```
module.exports = function (defaults) {
  var app = new Angular2App(defaults, {
      vendorNpmFiles: [
          'a2-in-memory-web-api/web-api.js'
      ]
  });
  return app.toTree();
}
```

(where *a2-in-memory-web-api/web-api.js* is a file in my *node_modules* folder)

In the **index.html** you add the following line:

```
<script src="vendor/a2-in-memory-web-api/web-api.js"></script>
```

Finally you restart your server.

Haven't tested it with angular material but you get the idea.

Comment: The new description in the Angular CLI wiki worked for me. Thanks for adding the link.

Comment: How do you know what files to include in vendorNpmFiles?  Some packages have lots of js files in their module

Comment: You can use wildcards to include them all

Comment: Is the wiki link broken? I just end up on the wiki start page.

Comment: Now that angular-cli has adopted webpack iso system.js, this answer doesn't make a lot of sense anymore.

Comment: After I follow the guidelines in the third party library installation - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation
I had that error saying:
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_angular2_notifications__.method is not a function(…)
@DavidBulté

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea - maybe something with the latest version of anguar2 notifications?

Comment: That documentation doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Updated the links

Answer (score 2):

Try configuring `SystemJS` in the `index.html` like this:

```js
System.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'node_modules/ng2-material': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'ng2-material/all': 'node_modules/ng2-material/all'
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work: `angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/node_modules/ng2-material/all.js(…)Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:1243` Problem is, when starting the dev server with `ng serve` files are not served from the project's root but from a generated `dist` folder. However, the data is somehow cached. Adding or removing files from `dist` doesn't change anything, and I don't know how to tell angular-cli to copy the ng2-material files.

Comment: PS: a workaround for this is copying the node_module-files to the src-folder "cp -r node_modules/ng2-material src/node_modules/ng2-material", which makes angular-cli copy the files as part of the project's source. however then the error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" appears when SystemJS loads the ng2-material module.

Comment: PPS: the "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" can be prevented by changing `format: 'register'` to `format: 'cjs'` in `System.config`'s `'node_module/ng2-material'` section. but then `angular2-polyfills.js` starts spitting out the error `Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined`

Comment: after stopping the server and restarting it (`ng serve`) it now works! though, it's still not clear how to correctly configure angular-cli so that `node_modules/ng2-material` doesn't have to be copied to `src/node_modules/ng2-material`

Comment: I spent a long time installing angular2-localstorage in a angular-cli generated project. Have no luck so far, getting 404. Tried the wiki link for adding 3rd party libs. It contains ts files, no js. I will try this work around of copying file from node_modules folder to the src folder.