# How do I get angular 2 cli to copy css and other necessary files to dist folder

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, ember-cli

I have set up an angular 2 typescript solution and added the material angular 2 npm package.

```
npm install -g angular-cli
ng new PROJECT_NAME
cd PROJECT_NAME
ng build
```

Everything is nicely copied from my scaffolded source folder to a dist folder.

Then I add the angular 2 material npm package:

```
npm install ng2-material --save
```

But what do I do from here? How do I tell the build command to copy the necessary files from node_modules to the dist folder.

And where is the magic located that makes sure that these files get copied to the dist/vendor folder?

```
<body>
  <timer-app>Loading...</timer-app>

  <script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>

  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
...
```

My package file ends up looking like this:
https://gist.github.com/nikolaj-kaplan/e85d5805fd67c3ba3f1f

I hope my confusion comes from a lack of knowledge about npm. And not angular cli. (Because more people will be able to help me). But I haven't got a whole lot of experience in either.

## Edit:

I did like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35900837/564623

```
module.exports = function (defaults) {
  var app = new Angular2App(defaults, {
      vendorNpmFiles: [
          'node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css'
      ]
  });
  return app.toTree();
}
```

Now my files are copied. Still don't understand how the other files in the dist-folder gets copied. The vendorNpmFiles array was empty.

Comment: I don't know if angular-cli can already do this, but i use `gulp` after npm update to copy the vendor files from the node_modules folder :)

Comment: All the script files from my html-snippet above are copied from the nodes_module folder to the dist-folder when I call the ng build or ng serve. But I can't figure out how this happens and how I get it to work with new modules.

Comment: Your workaround doesn't work. I'm trying with bootstrap.

Comment: @Nikolaj: I'm facing the same problem - need to use `typescript-collections` and bootstrap, but it doesn't copy its fileds to `dist/vendor/whatever`. Did you figure it out? I believe the installed package needs a `packages.json` specially crafted to make this work out of the box - I saw some specific properties in some packages that work, namely `_location`, `_installable`, etc, which seems to affect this behaviour. +1

Answer (score 3):

You don't need node_modules/ prefix, vendorNpmFiles automatically search in node_modules

```js
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: In case it's not clear, this is `angular-cli-build.js` (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: And if it helps, I believe the `link` tag would be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css">`.

Comment: Yep in angular-cli-build.js, sorry ;-)

Comment: The latest angular-cli switched to webpack, there is no `angular-cli-build.js` now.

Answer (score 1):

With a project created with angular-cli you have the file **.angular-cli.json** where you should add the css in the "styles" section array, for example, to include the bootstrap css inside node_modules I add the following line:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

I hope this help you