# Create an addon for angular-cli

Tags: angular

I just started a new project with `angular-cli` and need to implement some addons for specific needs of this project.

I found the commend `ng addon <addon-name>`, which is based on `ember-cli` addon creation, but that really creates a ember-cli addon which looks completely alien to angular-cli.

So, I inspired myself on angular-cli firebase addon and created this file in `<my-project>/addons/i18n-json/index.js`.

```
'use strict';

var i18nJson = {
    name: 'i18n-json',
    description: 'Generate an i18n JSON file from a string properties file.',
    works: 'insideProject',

    availableOptions: [{
        name: 'input',
        type: String,
        default: 'i18n/i18n.properties',
        description: 'i18n properties file'
    }, {
        name: 'output',
        type: String,
        default: 'dist/i18n/i18n.json',
        description: 'new JSON file to be generated with i18n strings'
    }],

    run: function(options, rawArgs) {
        console.log(1111, 'i18n-json', 'run'); // XXX
    }
};

module.exports = {
    name: 'i18n-json',

    includedCommands: function() {
        return {
            'i18n-json': i18nJson
        }
    }
};
```

Then, added `"addons/i18n-json"` to `angular-cli.json`'s "addons" section.

Problem: `ng` command doesn't recognise it.

Tried both globally installed script and `./node_modules/.bin/ng` but now got to the point I can't still understand why it's not showing any reaction.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

When I enter `ng addon help` in version 1.0.0-beta.17 of the CLI I get:

`You cannot use the addon command inside an angular-cli project.`

---

However, see @David Bulté's answer here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35900837/1762493

> Check the sections '3d party lib installation' and 'global lib installation' on the [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Stories#app-creation-using-template) Wiki:
>
> **App Creation Using Template**
>
> `ng new my-todo-app --template=simple-todo`
>
> `ng serve`
>
> **Using A Template Library**
>
> `ng new my-todo-app`
>
> `# Could be`  ``` ng use`` as well. ```
>
> `ng install complex-todo-addon`
>
> `ng generate todo routes/+todo`
>
> **Thirdparty Installation**
>
> `ng new my-todo-app`
>
> `ng install sass`

---

Possibly related question here:

- [Angular CLI addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823684/angular-cli-addon?rq=1)